# Приходит пустой $request на Laravel контроллер при отправке FormData через Axios

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Есть необходимостью с фронта на vue вместе с обычными данными отправлять файл в запросе по API.
Делаю `FormData`

```js
makeFormData(data) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const key in data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(data[key]))
    } else {
      formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }
  }
  return formData;
}
```

Отправляю запрос через axios

```js
// Метод компонента
async update() {
   this.isLoaded = false;
   const formData = this.makeFormData(this.invoice);
   const res = await invoiceAPI.update(this.invoice.id, formData);
   this.invoice = res.data.data;
   this.initInvoiceState();
   this.isLoaded = true;
   this.showToast("ОК", "Счёт изменён", "success");
},
// Инстанс axios в invoiceAPI
async update(id, invoice){
    const url = '/api/v1/invoices/' + id;
    return defaultAPIInstance.put(url, invoice, {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        }
    });
},
//в defaultAPIInstance прописывается токен авторизации.
```

в контроллере просто пытаюсь вывести request для теста

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
    $invoice->update($request->all());

    return $request->all();
    // $file = $request->file('file');
    // $invoice->file = $file->store('invoices');
    // $invoice->save();

    $this->updateInvoicePositions($invoice, $request->get('positions'));
    $this->createInvoicePositions($invoice, $request->new_positions);
    $this->destroyInvoicePositions($invoice, $request->deleted_positions_ids);

    $this->checkInvoiceStatus($invoice);

    return new InvoiceResource($invoice->fresh());
}
```

Проблема в том что все данные в полезной нагрузке запроса есть, но `$request` пустой приходит и до отправки файла дело не доходит.
Вот заголовки в которых всё вроде бы ОК

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2567
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBRdveT6Ekcie8afX
Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8001
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8001/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Уже много чего перепробовал, но так и не разобрался в чём проблема. Если просто отправлять объект, то всё ОК, проблема только с `FormData`. Может быть есть какой нибудь другой вариант отправки файла на бэк одним запросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод POST и добавите это на form-data

```
formData.append('_method', 'put')
```

чтоб получить данные

Comment: Не знаю в чём тут магия, но это сработало

Comment: Да просто method put не получает данные отправлено form-data